# Why can not pust local gitbook to gitbook.com?

Tags: git, gitbook

I follow official doc to update my gitbook using GIT:

```
touch README.md SUMMARY.md
git init
git add README.md SUMMARY.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add gitbook https://git.gitbook.com/{{UserName}}/{{Book}}.git
git push -u -f gitbook master
```

After executing `git push` it throws error:

> remote: Book not found fatal: repository
>   'https://git.gitbook.com/xxx/yyy.git/' not found

`xxx` is my gitbook username, `yyy` is my space n me, could someone give me a hand?

[image]

jackmeng is my username.
jack is my organization.
note is my space name.
Please correct me.

Comment: You can reveal the name of the git repo (i.e. your username and book name). I have a suspicion that one of those two is not correct and you're pointing to a bad repository

Comment: Thanks for your response.  https://git.gitbook.com/jackmeng/note.git is my remote url. the browser displays API method not found after visiting the url

Comment: I uploaded screenshot about my gitbook info, Is there anything worng in my url?

Comment: The commands and repo look correct from git's perspective, but I am not all that familiar with gitbook. The error is a bit odd, though, since there's a trailing `/` character. Are you sure you typed it correctly?

Comment: What's the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: gitbook https://git.gitbook.com/jackmeng/note.git (fetch)
gitbook https://git.gitbook.com/jackmeng/note.git (push)

Comment: I have no idea about this issue.

Comment: Try `git remote set-url gitbook https://git.gitbook.com/jackmeng/note.git`, and then try `git push -u -f gitbook master` again.

Comment: it did not work. same as before

Comment: From git's perspective, it looks okay to me. Are you *absolutely certain* that you're pointing to the right remote URL? git is telling you that it can't find that particular remote, so I am dubious that it's the right remote. This part no one can help you with: you'll have to get the correct url from the gitbook service.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your suggestion. I am certain sure the url is right.  unless the official document is incorrect. I will keep researching this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the space name is the same as the book name? The url you have above says it wants the book name: not the space name. Based on the screenshot I'd agree that your username looks correct.

Comment: I only create new space on gitbook.com, I can not find where add a new book, so I   consider that space name is book name.

Comment: That is probably not correct. Those two words do not share any meaning in English . I am not a gitbook user: you'll have to figure out how to create a book and/or what the remote is you have to point to.

Comment: I figured this out!  "Book"  is used in legecy.gitbook.com, "Space" is used in www.gitbbok.com, Please see new document here: https://docs.gitbook.com/getting-started/starting-a-project-on-gitbook,  "Space" replaces "book", Thank your advise!  On new version of gitbook.com, what I need to do is integrating target space with target github repository, then sync work automated done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Book" is used in legecy.gitbook.com, "Space" is used in www.gitbbok.com, Please see new document here: https://docs.gitbook.com/getting-started/starting-a-project-on-gitbook,  "Space" replaces "book".
If you want to integrate with github, what you need to do is integrating target space with target github repository, then sync work automated done.

[image]